# Colimit of Chow groups on Zariski open subschemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, k-theory, algebraic-vector-bundles, algebraic-cycles

Given a smooth affine scheme $X$, let's consider $\varinjlim\limits_{U\subset X}\tilde{K}_0(U)$, where $\tilde{K}_0(U)$ is the reduced zero-th $K$-group of the Zariski open subscheme $U$. Note that since algebraic vector bundles are Zariski locally trivial this implies that this colimit is zero. Specially this implies that $\varinjlim\limits_{U\subset X}CH^i(U)\otimes \mathbb{Q}=0$. Here $CH^i(U)$ is the Chow group of codimension $i$ cycles. The colimit $\varinjlim\limits_{U\subset X}CH^i(U)$ is also equal to zero. Since for any cycles restricting to its complement, will send the cycles to zero by localization.

Is it possible to get an idea what the  $\varinjlim\limits_{U\subset X}C^d(U)$ looks like when the base field is $\mathbb{C}$? where $C^d(U)$ is the $Mor(U,C_d(Y))$. Here $C_d(Y)$ is the Chow variety of codimension $d$ cycles of a fixed variety $Y$ and the colimit is taken as the colimit of topological spaces.

Comment: What is the topology on $C^d(U)$?

Comment: It is the topology induced from $\mathbb{C}$. Chow variety is complex variety so you can consider analytic topology on it.

Comment: The chow veriety is fine for $Y$ a projective variety I think. But then what is the topology on $Mor(U, C_d(Y))$? There is a notion of Hom-schemes $Hom(X, Y)$, which represent the functor $V\mapsto Hom_{Var/k}(X\times V, Y\times V)$. Is that what you want to take?

Comment: The $Mor$ means algebraic morphism, it is considered as a subspace of continuous mapping space with compact-open topology.

Answer (score 0):

**For $i>0$**: If $Z$ is a codimension $i$ for $i>0$ irreducible subvariety in $U$, certainly under the restriction map  $$CH^i(U)\to CH^i(U-Z)$$
$$Z\mapsto 0$$
So in the colimit $\varinjlim\limits_{U\subset X}CH^i(U)$, $Z\mapsto 0$.

**For $i=0$**: if $X$ is irreducible, then $\varinjlim\limits_{U\subset X}CH^0(U)\simeq \mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: I don't understand why $Z$ goes to zero? Isn't it possible for $Z$ to be equivalent to another cycle in $U$ that its immediate image is not zero?

Comment: I see the first statement that $Z$ goes to zero follows from localizations sequence, ok it was way too obvious. I changed the question a little bit.